# Start Websphere Application Server but not loading any application

Tags: websphere

Is there any way that we can start Websphere Application Server but not loading any applications installed on it?

Environment: websphere 7.0

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find a command line tool method for doing this, but you can edit the `deployment.xml` files underneath each WAR/EAR file that you want to stop from auto-starting when Websphere starts up.

These `deployment.xml` files are located typically here:

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/<my profile>/config/cells/<my cell>/applications/<my .ear>/deployments/<my app>/deployment.xml
```

Within this file is this XML snippet:

```
<targetMappings xmi:id="DeploymentTargetMapping_1499739616851" enable="true" target="ServerTarget_1499739616851"/>
```

Change the `enable=true` to `enable=false` for every EAR/WAR that you don't want to auto-start. Once done start WAS as you'd normally do so.

#### References

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21265381

Answer (score 1):

If you mean not starting installed applications, this is controlled through Administrative Console in Enterprise Applications > your_app > Target specific application status. There you can enable or disable auto start.

[Target specific application status](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rtargetmap.html)

Comment: I know the auto-start setting in Target Specific Application allows us to control if an installed application start with the server or not. But is it possible to control this through some server startup command parameters?